# duplicating elements in a grid jpanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

im trying to make a grid layout that randomly assigns letters to different coordinates in the grid. However, ive managed to make it mostly work, but it seems to only allow one of the same letter and doesnt duplicate it.. i need there to be more of the same letters around the grid (if that makes sense). ive tried to figure it out and reckon it might be a small error.. could anyone point me in the right direction? any help would be greatly appreciated..

```
gridPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(X, Y));
        grid = new JPanel[X][Y];    
        bug = new JLabel("O");
        obstacle = new JLabel("X");
        food = new JLabel("F");
        empty = new JLabel(" ");

        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < X; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Y; j++) {
                grid[i][j] = new JPanel();
                grid[i][j].setBackground(Color.white);
                grid[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory
                        .createLineBorder(Color.black));
                gridPanel.add(grid[i][j]);
                int num = r.nextInt(10); 
                if (num == 2) { 
                    grid[i][j].add(food); 
                } else if (num == 9) { 
                    grid[i][j].add(obstacle);
                } else if (num == 5) {
                    grid[i][j].add(bug);                                            
                } else {
                    grid[i][j].add(empty); 
                }
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to add a JLabel multiple times to your GUI, and this cannot be done.

You can add a GUI component to one and only one container. Consider filling your grid with JLabels and simply setting their text when needed. i.e., not swapping components, but swapping the state of your components.

Either that or using a method to create your JLabels when needed.

Comment: how would i do that? quite new to java